# No 'post' object available in Octopress

Tags: post, view, octopress

I just installed octopress as a blogging system and built my own little theme.
Everything works fine but there's one thing which isn't working yet.

Within a single post view, I don't seem to have a 'post' object. Which means that:

```
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
```

Generates an empty string. The blog index and the single post view are using the same article header. It's only the single post view where it doesn't work. The blog index works fine.

Does anybody of you know, which object is available for me in a single post view, or how I can access just the title of a post in a single post view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post object is created by the post loop and only available inside of the loop.

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}  
  <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

When it comes to generating the page itself, you'll access page data with teh `page` object.

```
<h1>{{ page.title }}<h1>
```

That will get the title for the page currently being generated which is probably what you want to be doing.

Comment: Exactly. Didn't changed that snippet. Still doesn't work. Anyway. Tried it with a new fresh installation. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>` is part of custom section?
If you want to add a section to your sidebar, create a new file in `source/_includes/custom/asides/`.
Whenever you add a section to the sidebar, follow this pattern, with a `<section>` block and an `<h1>` for a title. To add it to the sidebar, edit the `_config.yml` and add it to the list of asides.
[More info](http://octopress.org/docs/theme/template/)